# How to set height of empty div inside table cell to height of that cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table cell as,

```
<td>
   <div style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%">   
     <div class="drag-row"   
          style="position:absolute;height:3px;width:100%;left:0px;top:100%;">
      </div>
      TEXT
   </div>
</td>
```

If **td** height is lets say 100px, `TEXT` comes in vertical-center of table cell and its parent **div** has the height same as `TEXT` followed by **div** of class `drag-row`. But i want the height of parent **div** to match the height of **td** followed by **div** of class `drag-row` (so this div should come at the bottom border of table cell)

If I set the height of parent div to height of td using javascript, it may work, but in that case if height of that cell gets updated later, my div would not update its height as script has run. 
So I want to do it by css.   Thanks.

This explanation may be confusing so my actual problem is, I want `drag-row` div at the bottom of table-cell.

Comment: @Mr_Green In plain and simple, i want my `drag-row` div at the bottom of table-cell.

Comment: Set top:100px instead of 100%

Comment: I am also very confused as to what you want... if you just want the `drag-row` div at the bottom of the cell, add `bottom:0;` to it. f it is overlapping the text, just add a `margin:XXpx;` to the table cell (where XXpx = height of `drag-row`).

Comment: @jegesh i said td-height = 100px just for example. I can not set top to absolute values because my table-cell height may change later. so i need top in percentage only

Comment: First of all, your html layout is not good. you should have two different div's instead of the nested div's.

Comment: @robooneus Sorry if it looks like I copied from you. I was already writing the answer when I saw your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `top:100%` use `bottom:0`. Then the bottom of the `div` will always match the bottom of the parent element.